# How to Use ASP.NET Membership Provider class

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership, roleprovider

i want to use asp.net membership provider for my own database i have own table

here is what have i done 
**i extended the membership provider class with my own write all overided methords.**
 is it right way to use membership provider class for custom use?? i also extend the rolemanagement class too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's "right" and what's "wrong" is hazy, as different people have different opinions.

My opinion is that you should never extend the membership tables, because by doing so you create potential problems down the road if Microsoft decides to add additional functionality to those classes.

Instead, you should simply use the asp.net membership provider keys as foreign keys into your own tables.  Thus, you might have your own "users" table, but one of the columns is the asp.net membership User ID value.  This allows you to relate them together and get at that information, without extending the asp.net membership tables themselves.

Comment: +1 a very good thought, I will implement in the same way. Thanks

Comment: i think your opinion is very effective but unclear is how we use both tables because primary table should be my own. only administrator allows to add uses too. any clues??

Comment: @gayancc - Umm.. i don't understand what you mean.  "unclear is how we use both tables"?  You use them just like any table in any database.  You write queries against them.  You use the asp.net userid as the key to join them.  I don't understand what's so difficult to undestand about that concept.  For example:  "SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName, myusers.FirstName FROM aspnet_Users INNER JOIN myusers ON aspnet_Users.UserId = myusers.UserID"

Comment: @gayancc - If only asministrators can add users, then you just remove the "register" link from the login controls, and you create a user interface to allow administrators to create new users using the Membership API and your own code to add your additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried implementing custom membership user, and succeeded after a month's effort. One idea I always have is, no one can ever generalize what our requirements should be, and especially a vendor should not decide in particular.

It is good we have a way to extend the membership user. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms366730.aspx) and [that](http://www.shiningstar.net/aspnet_articles/customprovider/CustomProvider.aspx) are the best resources to guide how to write a membership user.